# News ticker Like component for home page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, home-page-component

I am trying to create a new home page component that will display a scrolling message on the home page. The use case is to provide end users with tips and hints around general usage. This used to be possible by creating a html component but now that salesforce has changed the editor for this component and added a new Visualforce component type, I guess it will need to be done in Visualforce.

Can anyone provide a sample of what the VF page would need to look like?

Answer (score 3):

Here are steps for you:

1) Create new VF page with following code

```
    <apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->


  <marquee bgcolor="orange" width="100%" height="200" direction="UP"> 
    1) THis is item 1111  <br/>
    2) THis is item 2222  <br/>
    3) THis is item 3333  <br/>
    4) THis is item 4444  <br/>
    5) THis is item 5555  <br/>
    6) THis is item 6666  <br/>
    7) THis is item 7777  <br/>    


  </marquee>

  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

2) Then Go to setup -> home page components -> new
create a component with VF page and on narrow (left)  section

3) Then update your home page layout and enable this component.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [*jQuery webticker*](http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/). You can then add plain HTML to your VF page:

```
<ul id="webticker">
    <li>
        Some text one
    </li>
     <li>
        Some text two
    </li>
     <li>
        Some text three
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can activate the webticker with this jQuery code:

```
$("#webticker").webTicker();
```

Do not forget to add the required resources (you will find all needed info in the link provided)